# iOS - GPUImage distorted

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimage, gpuimage, gpuimagestillcamera

I am using GPUImage to apply live filters on camera views. the problem is once I capture an image, it gets pixelated
Here is my code:

in viewDidLoad:

```
imageCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
imageCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
normalImgView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-100)];
[normalImgView setFillMode:kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatioAndFill];
```

And this is how I am capturing the image:

```
[imageCamera capturePhotoAsImageProcessedUpToFilter:selectedFilter withCompletionHandler:^(UIImage *processedImage, NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"processedImage %@", processedImage);

    NSData *dataForPNGFile = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(processedImage, 1.0);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSError *error2 = nil;
    if (![dataForPNGFile writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FilteredPhoto.jpg"] options:NSAtomicWrite error:&error2])
    {
        return;
    }

    if (processedImage) {
        //Display it in an image view
    }
}];
```

I added break points to track the execution and see in which part exactly the image gets pixelated. It was the GPUImageOutput 's imageFromCurrentFramebufferWithOrientation: at this line:

```
CGImageRef cgImageFromBytes = [self newCGImageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];
```

newCGImageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput always returns nil

```
- (CGImageRef)newCGImageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput;
{
    return nil;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Something doesn't make sense in what you've described. If you got a nil image back, you wouldn't see anything at all, not a pixellated image. Also, that version of `-newCGImageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput` is from the generic GPUImageOutput superclass, not GPUImageFilter, so you should never get to that when dealing with a filter or subclass. Make sure you aren't trying to capture directly from your camera, which doesn't currently implement that method.